# NodeJS MySQL - Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection for long running queries

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using node-mysql package in my NodeJS project. I want to run long running queries in MySQL to audit the data.

My connection is getting timed out exactly after 10 minutes and I get following error

`Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.`

I am already using connection pool with the following settings

```js
connectTimeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
acquireTimeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
connectionLimit: 500,
debug: false,
```

running the same query using MySQL client is executed in (5 min 56.38 sec).

The same query in my project is timed out exactly after 10 minutes.

I also tried passing timeout in query options but it didn't work.

Please suggest me a way to execute long running queries in MySQL using NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust the `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` settings on the MySQL server. These settings can be adjusted in the MySQL configuration file (e.g., my.cnf or my.ini) or modified dynamically using SQL commands.

These settings control the maximum time in seconds that the server waits for activity on a non-interactive connection before closing it.

Check this out https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But why the query is executed in 5min using MySQL client, and is timed out in 10min when running from nodejs?

Comment: I'm not sure why, looking at the code could help.